# Adding tab delimiter in a string

Tags: c#

I have an API that consumes Memorystream and writes to a text file. I have string with tab delimiter to be converted to Memory Stream and I had to use Encoding code page 850 to get it into an MS DOS style txt file. I had tried using \t character but it is getting treated as literal

```
string fieldDelimiter  = @"\t";

var dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
dataBuilder.Append(Field1);
dataBuilder.Append(fieldDelimiter);
dataBuilder.Append(Field2);

var stream = MemoryStream(Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetBytes(dataBuilder.ToString())); 
// API call to persist Stream to txt file.
```

What is the correct way to go about getting the tab delimiter in this case.

Comment: remove **`@`**.  `const fieldDelimiter = "\t";` Then read some c# docs about        [String literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@` symbol instructs the CLR to interpret the following string literally, ignoring what would otherwise be escape characters. In other words, considering the following:

```
const fieldDelimiter1 = @"\t";
const fieldDelimiter2 = "\\t";
```

`fieldDelimiter1==fieldDelimiter2` would evaluate to `true`.

As L.B stated. Drop the `@` and you'll have your desired results.

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment, since it actually answers the question. You should try to avoid answering in comments, because we can't accept comments as the answer.

Comment: Yep, I hate the comment "feature" too, but good catch on this, you will be at 50 in no time!

Comment: Oops. I didnt recognise i was escaping back slash. Thanks